# Issue with draw bitmap on canvas that doesn't work with particular device

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a special issue with drawBitmap on Canvas object.

I use a classic Canvas for a minesweeper game published on Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ssaurel.minesweeper).

The game draws a board with cells. Cells are bitmaps drawn on a Canvas. All work normally on Android devices and the result is like this :

[image: Board displayed normally]

The problem comes with 2 kinds of devices : Alcatel and Wiko.

In details, it concerns Alcatel One Touch MPop, Wiko Cink Slim and Wiko Cink Peax.

All have Android 4.1 installed but I think Android version is not problem because others users on others smartphones have Android 4.1 and it works well.

For these devices, it appears like this :

[image: Board displayed on Wiko device]

Unfortunately, it's impossible to reproduce that bug on emulator. I think, I have problem to have identical configuration on emulator to Wiko or Alcatel devices.

I made special version of APK with debug traces to user of these devices. The log seems identical with others devices that work. Drawables are loaded normally, sizes are good, position where they are drawn also, ...

So, I don't know what can be the reason of that. Why it works everywhere but not on these devices. What is the particularity of these devices ?

For example, the code in canvas where I draw cells (that are bitmaps) is like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsX; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rowsY; j++) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(content[i][j].getBitmap(),i * blockSize, j * blockSize, null);
    }
}
```

Nothing is special in that code. Paint object is null but I also tried to put an instance like that : new Paint() and the result is the same.

In addition, i asked to try the same code but with a canvas.drawRect. The result is good and the rectangle is drawn :

[image]

So, the problem comes really from the bitmap that is not drawn where as it's well loaded, well scaled, and it has correct size. Very strange.

So, someone would have an idea about the problem ? Or, others tests that I can make ?

Thanks for your help.

Sylvain

Comment: What's the size of the bitmap? Also, show your logcat, please.

Comment: It's the problem. I don't have access to logcat because I don't have these devices. I have just some logs that I had be able to collect from users that I sent special APK version with traces. But in this trace the bitmaps have a size.

Comment: I have faced a similar problem. In my case, I had a large bitmap in the drawable folder and none on the qualified folders. Android assumes drawables without a density qualifier are mdpi and scales them up or down for other densities.

Comment: Indeed, the drawables are only present on drawable folder with no qualifier. These drawables are not present in drawables folders with qualifiers. So, I should put these drawables in drawable-nodpi to see if they are drawn ?

Comment: Yes, this could be a good approach. The system does not scale resources tagged with -nodpi qualifier.

Comment: I'm going to try that way but it seems strange that the problem be just on these devices Alcatel and Wiko ?

Comment: Not so strange; there is a hardware limitation on the texture sizes. For example, the Wiko Cinc Slim only supports textures up to 2048x2048 http://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx27&os=Android&api=gl&D=Wiko+Cink+slim&testgroup=gl How big are your textures in the drawable folder?

Comment: There are no so big. There are several textures and not an uniq texture that I cut when i load them. So, for example for a cell it's just a 16 x 16 pixels image.

Comment: Put these drawables to drawable-nodpi was the good solution. Thanks a lot man !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the size of a bitmap. I had the same problem. Too big bitmap causes it not draw at all (without any error).